# Retrieve variable from Applescript in Shell

Tags: bash, shell, spotify

So, I'm trying to build a very small shell script that grabs the currently playing Spotify song and returns the lyrics of the song in the terminal.

**What works**

The applescript returns/echos the track name to the terminal

**What I need help with**

I can't seem to retrieve values of `theArtist and theName` from the applescript, to use in the curl command below.

Any tips on how to make this work? :)

```
echo "tell application \"Spotify\"
        set theTrack to current track
        set theArtist to artist of theTrack
        set theName to name of theTrack
    end tell" | osascript

song=`curl -s "http://makeitpersonal.co/lyrics?artist=$theArtist&title=$theName"`

echo -e "$theArtist - $theName\n$song"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
# Get information from Spotify via AppleScript and store it in shell variables:
IFS='|' read -r theArtist theName <<<"$(osascript <<<'tell application "Spotify"
        set theTrack to current track
        set theArtist to artist of theTrack
        set theName to name of theTrack
        return theArtist & "|" & theName
    end tell')"

# Create *encoded* versions of the artist and track name for inclusion in a URL:
theArtistEnc=$(perl -MURI::Escape -ne 'print uri_escape($_)' <<<"$theArtist")
theNameEnc=$(perl -MURI::Escape -ne 'print uri_escape($_)' <<<"$theName")

# Retrieve lyrics via `curl`:
lyrics=$(curl -s "http://makeitpersonal.co/lyrics?artist=$theArtistEnc&title=$theNameEnc")

# Output combined result:
echo -e "$theArtist - $theName\n$lyrics"
```

- AppleScript implicitly returns the result of the last statement; thus, in order to return multiple items of information, build up a string to return with an explicit `return` statement .
- You then need to parse the output string into its components using `read` (here I've chosen `|` as a separator, because it's unlikely to be contained in artist names or song titles) and assign them to *shell variables* (AppleScript is an entirely separate world, and its variables are not accessible to the shell - the information must be passed via output string).
- For the `curl` command to work, the information you splice into the URL must be *properly URL-encoded* (e.g., `Pink Floyd` must be encoded as `Pink%20Floyd`), which is what the `perl` commands do.

Comment: @user2656127: You're welcome; there was a problem with your `curl` command, too, which definitely prevented lyrics retrieval - see my update; not sure how good that online source is in principle, though.